# Can someone explain the error in my C# do while loop?

Tags: c#, loops, do-while

Simple question I suspect but I can't find an answer online. I'm trying to get this do while loop to loop infinitely until the number seven is given.

```
namespace Practice_code
{          
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int answer;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
                int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());       

                if (answer == 7)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well done chum!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nope try again.");
                }
            } while (answer != 7);    

        }         
    }
}
```

The first answer in the do while loop returns this error:
Error   CS0136  A local or parameter named 'answer' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

The answer in the while condition returns:
Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'answer

I can get rid of the second error by defining answer with a random number at the start. But I can't get rid of the first.

Comment: Typo: you're redeclaring the `answer` variable inside the loop. Get rid of `int` from `int answer` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring `answer` inside the loop which you can't do.

Try replacing

`int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

with

`answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: I feel impossibly stupid, hahaha. Thank you for pointing out something so obvious.